youtube live stream health status always returns "nodata" and never transitions to active state
I am sending a HLS stream to youtube live, but for some reason, the health status of the live stream always returns "nodata" and never transitions to 'active' state. I have verified and tested the HLS stream with custom server and the stream plays just fine. I have verified the key and the ingestion URL, audio bit rate, video and audio codecs. All look fine and as per the spec. I am looking for a check list on what else I need to check for things to work.

Youtube live stream expects an audio track, for stream to start, send a null or silent audio track for the stream to be accepted. The youtube live stream will transition to active in no time.
